# How to get props auto-complete inside a React component using prop-types

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-proptypes

I would like get VSCode intellisense inside a functional component for `props`. Note that this is already working in Webstorm. For example, if I would type `props.meta`, I would like to get an auto-complete window listing the properties in the PropTypes.shape function. See the image below for a visual example.

```
SEO.propTypes = {
      lang: PropTypes.string,
      meta: PropTypes.shape({
        yoast_wpseo_title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        yoast_wpseo_metadesc: PropTypes.string,
      })
    }
```

[image]

Please note that I don't use TypeScript in this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use typescript you'll have to use something like `propTypes` otherwise how is VSCode going to know what to autocomplete with.